# Data Sync from wearable to handset

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I want to create a wear app that I can start on my phone, and upon start queries my handset to do some network io, which then packages the result into a format that I can render back on the wearable device.

I want to have the handset store some settings data, that will be used automatically when the wear app starts.

My question is, what is the best flow for this kind of scenario. There are many options for data sync between the two when looking at:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

My thoughts were as follows, but if this is not the best way to achieve this please let me know.

1) Open app, start an activity that sends a message with  Wearable.MessageApi to the handset.

2) Have a service on the handset extending WearableListenerService that does the network io / payload generation.

3) Have the handset send this back again using the message API

4) Have a listener service on the wearable to listen for this response.

If there is a more reasonable way to achieve something similar please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the best approach to archive you goal is:

- Introduce business object model (for settings, etc) which is the same for the handset and wearable apps.
- Every app (handset and wearable) should keep its own copy of this data in its own data storage.
- Every app (handset and wearable) which alters data synchronize these changes with other app by `WearableListenerService`. You can find example here - [Handling Data Layer Events](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html)
- Use `MessageApi` as “control protocol” - one app can say another what to do, for example open some activity or start some background process (networking, etc). You can find an example here - [Sending and Receiving Messages](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)